# Indirect include dependency not resolved in Visual Studio Build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Visual Studio sometimes misses out on an indirect build dependency where the change in a class definition should trigger a rebuild in a `.cpp` file that depends on it via two indirect includes.

The question is now: is this a bug or is this to be expected? How exactly does Visual Studio determine whether an object file is up-to-date or not?

To illustrate the problem, here's a breakdown of the setting.

In file `A.h` in project `ProjectA`:

```
class A
{
    virtual void x() = 0;
};
```

In file `B.h` in `ProjectB`:

```
#include "A.h"
class B : public A
{
    virtual void y() = 0;
};
```

In file `C.h` in `ProjectC`:

```
#include "B.h"
class C : public B
{
    void x() override;
    void y() override;
};
```

and in file `C.cpp`:

```
#include "C.h"
void C::x() {}
void C::y() {}
```

Finally, C is instantiated in `D.cpp`:

```
#include "C.h"
void somefunction()
{
    auto p = make_shared<C>();
}
```

Now I add method `virtual void z() = 0;` to class `A`, which - so I do expect - should cause a recompilation of `C.cpp` and a failure in `D.cpp` because of the missing implementation of `z()`. But sporadically, Visual Studio tells me everything is up to date and no change in `A.h` triggers a recompilation of `D.cpp` which then leads to a lengthy search for program failures that ends in a rebuild after which all works as expected again.

To be clear, with a rebuild before adding `z()`, changing `A.h`'s timestamp triggers the expected, IMHO correct behavior. and I cannot willingly reproduce.

Comment: Have you enabled minimal rebuild (/Gm)?

Comment: does projectB depend on projectA, and projectC on projectB? (right-click project in solution explorer, select 'Project Dependencies') sidenote: the code as shown is not enough to reproduce the issue, it won't link.

Comment: No, the consistent setting through all projects is `/Gm-`

Comment: @stijn No, since `A` and `B` are pure virtual. I would accept this as an explanation if it'd always fail, but it works most of the time.

Comment: Good point. I can actually reproduce the issue here, oddly enough I never had problems with such code structure in actual projects so I wonder what's going on.